# Exposing a <ip_address>/<port> to internet

Tags: windows, iis, ip, port, firewall

I have deployed an `ASP.net mvc` app to `IIS` and have added `ip_address` and port binding so that from google chrome, I can paste such a link:

```
http://(my_ip_address)/(port_number)
```

and I am accessing the home page of my MVC Web application. To do this, I have followed [this guide](https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2886/How-to-configure-IIS-to-access-website-using-IP-address.html).
Now, My question is: if I want some other user in another machine to be able to access the same application when I give him the link `http://[my_ip_address]/[my_port_number]`, How do I do that ?

I have opened that particular port in my machine firewall (added as a rule). But when another person from his different machine accesses it, It says:

> Site can't be reached, took too long to respond

I googled it a lot, but I am hitting the same point.

Comment: It's going to depend entirely on how your server's Internet connection works, and especially on what firewall(s) and/or NAT router(s) are between it and the Internet. I'm also not sure whether this is really the right forum for this question, but I'm also not sure which other SE site would be better.

Comment: Could you please tell me more details about your computer? Does this computer has the publi IP address? If you don't have the public IP address that means other machine coudln't access your site by using IP address by default.

Comment: yes,  this remote machine has public ip address.

Comment: I suggest you could try to use cmd ping command to ping the remote server by using the IP address to make sure you could access the server.